# How to get previous page after Login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Hi I am creating my first project in Asp.net Core and I need redirect user after Login to his previous page. For example if he will watch page "About" then he will want to Login and after Login I need him to redirect to "About" page. 
Here is my code in Controller.

```
 //
    // GET: /Account/Login
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/Account/Login")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_signInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
                _signInManager.SignOutAsync();


            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;

            return View("Login");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return ExceptionActionResult(e);
        }
    }
```

I tried to use Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString(); but the problem is that previous page is the log in page. I tried put this method in //Get Login but then I don't know how to send the string to the //Post Login

```
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/Account/Login")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        try
        {
            //Nesmi byt prihlasen
            if (_signInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
                return ErrorActionResult("User is already Signed");

          //  string var = Request.Headers["Referer"];
                string var = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();

            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                set lockoutOnFailure: true
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {

                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning(2, "someString");
                    ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "someString");
                    return View("Lockout");
                }
                else
                { 
                        _logger.LogWarning(2, "someString");
                        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid Password or Mail");
                    }


                    return View(model);

            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return ExceptionActionResult(e);
        }
    }
```

If you will need anything else or If you will not understand me ask me for details. I will be happy for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like below. Suppose the Action link for About looks like below

```
<a href="/Home/About">About</a>
```

Now when user clicks on About page he will be redirected to Log in Page which is below and because it's a GET request the URL will be the link to the `About page` and it will be captured in `string returnUrl`

```
  public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
  {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
  }
```

**See URL:**

[image]

And now as far as redirection is concerned, below is the code for login.cshtml. Notice how we are sending the `returnURl as Anonymous Object` when the form is POSTED.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = 
ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post)){
      @*LOGIN PAGE RAZOR LOGIC*@
}
```

**Login POST Controller action**

```
   [HttpPost]
   public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
   {
       return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
   }
```